# Keep background image animation going between pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a background image that's hues rotate using a css animation. When clicking to a new page on my website that has the same background image it starts again from the first hue, is there a way that would continue the animation going without it resetting everytime? p.s it is a wordpress website

```
#background-colour {
    -webkit-animation: changeColor 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
  0%   {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: You would have to use JS to load the new pages dynamically. Otherwise, you could have other animations that start later in the hue-changing process on pages that would generally be clicked to from the home page, etc.